apply different learning rate for introduced tokens in the transformers library
Say I want to introduce a few new tokens into the vocabulary of an existing model, and I want these tokens to have a different learning rate compared to the rest of the model's parameters during training. How can I implement this in the Transformers library?
Idealy I should still be able to use the transformer.Trainer class for the training.
